# how to set condition on onCreate() and onResume() on Android?

Tags: android, accelerometer, gyroscope, android-gravity

I'm working on an android project based on a motion sensor. For various purposes, I'm using an accelerometer, the gyroscope in my project.

Here is a scippet of **onCreate()** on **onResume()** method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /*To setup Gravity*/
        flickManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        Objects.requireNonNull(flickManager).registerListener(mSensorListener, flickManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        mAccel = 10f;
        mAccelCurrent = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
        mAccelLast = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
        /*End Here*/

        /*To setup YouTube API*/
        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
        /*---------End-------------------*/
        /*Setup the textbox*/
        txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ttview);
        txtview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ttview2);
        txtview3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ttview3);
        txtview4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ttview4);
        final EditText seekToText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.seek_to_text);
        /*-----------------End------------------------------*/

        /* Setup seekbar*/
        Button seekToButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seek_to_button);
        seekToButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int skipToSecs = Integer.valueOf(seekToText.getText().toString());
                player.seekToMillis(skipToSecs * 1000);
                Log.d("dur:"+skipToSecs * 1000,"Second");
            }
        });

 protected void onResume()
    {
        flickManager.registerListener(mSensorListener, flickManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        super.onResume();
        //accelerometer.register();
        //gyroscope.register();
    }
```

My approach is to check up some conditions first before activating any motion-based work.
Is it possible to set up any condition such as "If-else" here? If not what is the best practice will be to call them from outside of the method to see whether they should activate or not.

Thank you.

Comment: yeah you can setup any condition you want, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to use if-else condition on onResume() like
```if(flickManager.registerListener(mSensorListener, flickManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);)
{
    accelerometer.register();
}

```
But it doesn't respond to anything in the emulator, the app seems doesn't start at all.

Comment: If the app doesn't start it sounds like there's a crash somewhere. Can you check logcat for some logs?

Comment: Here it is:

``` 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.YouTilt/com.example.YouTilt.MainActivity}: android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.apps/com.example.apps.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onResume()
     Caused by: android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.apps/com.example.apps.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onResume()




```

This is what I'm having now.

Comment: Ah ok, so that error simply says that you need to call `super.onResume()` in `onResume()`. From your code, you don't seem to be doing so.

Comment: Is this like calling `super.onResume();` first, then setup if-else condition?

Comment: `protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if(flickManager.registerListener(mSensorListener, flickManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL))
        {
            accelerometer.register();
            gyroscope.register();
        }

    }`
My logic was if i can detect any shake/vibrating on phone then the accelerometer and gyroscope will start to work.